# Ошибка установления соединения с SQL Server после установки программы на другом компьютере

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-localdb

Мне нужна помощь с решением одной проблемы. Создал установщик приложения с помощью MS Visual Studio Installer Projects и запустил на другом устройстве, при загрузке sql localdb сначала получал данную ошибку "setup has detected that the file has changed since it was initially published", поискав в интернете не нашёл нормального решения и установил MS SQL Server 2017 LocalDB вручную. После этого при запуске программы получил следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажет кто-нибудь, как её исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я обнаружил, что не могу проверить версию SQL Server LocalDB, установленную на втором компьютере, через командную строку с помощью команды `sqllocaldb info MSSQLLocalDB` (получал ошибку).

Поэтому я решил пересоздать экземпляр MSSQLLocalDB, используя следующие команды:

1) `sqllocaldb d MSSQLLocalDB`

2) `sqllocaldb c MSSQLLocalDB`

И после этого программа успешно подключилась к базе данных.

Вдруг, кому тоже поможет.